# rosbridge can't be installed in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't install rosbridge for some reasons.
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server

The system is update and all the other packages are working fine. I'm using kinetic.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241583/rosbridge-can%27t-be-installed-in-ubuntu-16.04/) by [humanoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27737/humanoid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lots of users have requested a released version for Kinetic: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/214 , but the developers are still working on it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0